# UNC share directory does not exist

Tags: c#, permissions, unc, network-share

I have a C# process that needs to read a file existing in a share directory on a remote server.

The below code results in "Share does not exist." being written to the console.

```
string fileName = "someFile.ars";
string fileLocation = @"\\computerName\share\";
if (Directory.Exists(fileLocation))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Share exists.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Share does not exist.");
}
```

The process is run under an AD user account and the same account is granted Full Control permissions on the share directory. I can successfully map the share as a network drive on the machine the process resides on and can copy files to/from the directory. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: can the code access it if mapped?

Comment: Also, use `Path.Combine(fileLocation, fileName)` rather than `fileLocation+fileName`

Answer (score 2):

Use `File.Exists` rather than `Directory.Exists`.

Plus, you may want to be somewhat platform-agnostic and use the canonical `Path.Combine` as such:

```
string fileName = "someFile.ars";
string fileServer = @"\\computerName";
string fileLocation = @"share";
if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(fileServer, fileLocation, fileName)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Share exists.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Share does not exist.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone. Turns out I'm an idiot. We have a local AND an AD account with the same name and I was inadvertently running the process under the local account while the permissions on the share were for the AD account. Running the process under the AD account (really this time, I swear!) solved the issue. I did take your advice and used Path.Combine, however. Oh, and I can't answer myself since I have less than 10 rep :(